# How to restrict multiple inputs with checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I have a form with 6 inputs, the inputs are grouped by two and I enable/disable them using a checkbox like in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zpakbkp/).

How do I restrict the search? For example, I need to let the user know they need to fill both inputs if they select the *check1* checkbox, or if they selected checkboxes *check1* and *check2* that they need to fill all 4 inputs. Right now I have this:

```
if( (check1.checked || check2.checked || check3.checked) ){
    if($scope.tolPositivaDim1 == '' || $scope.tolNegativaDim1 == '' || 
       $scope.tolPositivaDim2 == '' || $scope.tolNegativaDim2 == '' || 
       $scope.tolPositivaDim3 == '' || $scope.tolNegativaDim3 == ''){
        console.log(''Need to fill all inputs);
    } else
    console.log('Something');
} else {
    console.log('Need to check at least one');
}
```

But with this it doesn't let me search until I have filled the six inputs. Is there a way to do this without having to do an `if` for each specific case?:

```
if(check1.checked)  || if(check1.checked && check2.checked).....
```

Answer (score 0):

You could improve the code to work with any number of such checkbox & double input combinations. Then define a handler for the form's `submit` event, and check that inputs are not empty when they are not disabled. If one of those is empty return `false`, so to cancel the submission.

Some of the code below uses ES6 features. If you cannot use those, it should not be hard to translate the idea to ES5:

```js
var checks = [...document.querySelectorAll('[id^=checkDimension]')], 
    positivaDims = [...document.querySelectorAll('[id^=tolPositivaDim')],
    negativaDims = [...document.querySelectorAll('[id^=tolNegativaDim')];

checks.forEach(function (check, i) {
  check.onchange = function() {
    positivaDims[i].disabled = !checks[i].checked;
    negativaDims[i].disabled = !checks[i].checked;
  }.bind(i);
  // call the above code also on page load, so to initialise the disabled
  // properties correctly:
  check.onchange();
});

document.forms[0].onsubmit = function (e) {
  if (positivaDims.concat(negativaDims).some(function (input) {
    // if for any non-disabled input the value is blank... 
    return !input.disabled && input.value == '';
  })) {
    alert('All inputs are required.');
    // cancel form submission (either of the two methods below will do it)
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="" method="post">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkDimension1"> Dimension 1</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tolPositivaDim1" placeholder="0.03" ng-model="tolPositivaDim1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tolNegativaDim1" placeholder="0.03" ng-model="tolNegativaDim1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkDimension2"> Dimension 2</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tolPositivaDim2" placeholder="0.03" ng-model="tolPositivaDim2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tolNegativaDim2" placeholder="0.03" ng-model="tolNegativaDim2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkDimension3"> Dimension 3</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tolPositivaDim3" placeholder="0.03" ng-model="tolPositivaDim3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tolNegativaDim3" placeholder="0.03" ng-model="tolNegativaDim3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right" >Search</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default pull-right">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

The same is also available in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zpakbkp/2/).